# Wicket textfield currency formatting on focus

Tags: formatting, wicket, textfield

What is considered as the best practice for formatting Wicket TextFields? E.g., I want currency fields to have a symbol and a comma. I have created a solution by using an IConverter implementation, and it kind of works.  But, I am not satisfied with the behavior on focus. I want the formatting to be removed on focus. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a jQuery plugin for that. I wouldn't do this in Wicket. Look at Google for *"jquery number format plugin"* or something like that. A few examples:

http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/

http://opensource.teamdf.com/number/examples/demo-as-you-type.html

Be aware that this plugins may interfere with `AjaxBehaviors` you use in your components. Just try a few and see which will suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

you could create a custom behavior:

```
public class CurrencyFormattingBehavior extends Behavior{
private static final long serialVersionUID = -4754030237711643182L;

private final String format;

public CurrencyFormattingBehavior(final String format){
    this.format = format;
}

@Override
public void renderHead(Component component, IHeaderResponse response) {
    super.renderHead(component, response);
    String script = "var currencyInputField = $('#"+component.getMarkupId()+"');"
            + "currencyInputField.on('focus', function(){"
            + "currencyInputField.val(currencyInputField.val().replace('"+format+"', ''));"
            + "});"
            + "currencyInputField.on('blur', function(){"
            + "currencyInputField.val(currencyInputField.val() + '"+format+"')"
            + "});";

    response.render(OnDomReadyHeaderItem.forScript(script));
  }
}
```

and then use it for any text field:

```
public class HomePage extends WebPage {

private final String testString = "";
  public HomePage(final PageParameters parameters) {
    super(parameters);
    TextField<String> textField = new TextField<String>("text", new PropertyModel<String>(this, "testString"));
    add(textField);
    textField.add(new CurrencyFormattingBehavior(" €"));
  }
}
```

but this is just a very very quick and simple example. for more advanced formatting i would suggest using regex.